# Linking HTML table with MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink, html-table

I have a table that displays data from a MySQL table. I have an extra column that adds a checkbox for each entry.

Is it possible to link that column row with the other data in the columns containing the MySQL data?

The checkbox entries will then be saved to a new mysql table upon pressing the 'Save' button.

Here is a picture to show you what I mean:

[image]

Code:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','root');

if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    if( isset( $_POST['cb_change'] ) && is_array( $_POST['cb_change'] ))
    {
        foreach( $_POST['cb_change']  as $emp_number => $permission)
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE `rights` SET Permission='".mysql_real_escape_string($permission)."' WHERE emp_number='".mysql_real_escape_string($emp_number)."'";
            echo __LINE__.": sql: {$sql}\n";
            mysql_query( $sql );
        }
    }
}
?>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size:36px;"><strong><span style="font-family: trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 128, 128);">File Database - Administration Panel</span></span></strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid #666;
font-style:Calibri;
}
th
{
background-color:#666;
color:white;
font-style:Calibri;
}
</style>
</head>

    <form method="post" action="admin.php">

    <?php 


        if (!$connection)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db('users', $connection);

        //mysql_query('INSERT into rights(Emp_num, ID, Name, Surname) SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname FROM hs_hr_employee');


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, Permissions FROM rights");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO rights (emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname)
                    SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname
                    FROM hs_hr_employee
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE employee_id = VALUES(employee_id), emp_number = VALUES(emp_number)
                    ");

        $duplicates = mysql_query("SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, count(*) FROM rights GROUP BY emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname having count(*) > 1");

        $count = mysql_num_rows($duplicates);

        if ($count > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($duplicates)) {
        $field = $row["emp_number"];
        $limit = $row["count(*)"] - 1;
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM rights WHERE emp_number='$field' LIMIT $limit");
        }
        mysql_free_result($duplicates);
        }           


        echo "<center>";

        echo "<table >
        <tr>
        <th>Employee Number</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Permissions</th>
        <th>Change</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_number'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['employee_id'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_firstname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_lastname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['Permissions'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td> <select name='cb_change[]'><option value='all'>All</option> <option value='remote'>Remote Gaming</option> <option value='landbased'>Landbased Gaming</option> <option value='general'>General Gaming</option> </select> </td>"; 
          echo "</tr>" ;
          }


          #echo "<td>" . $row['Change'] . "</td>";


          echo "</table>";

          echo "</center>";


        #$_POST['cb_permissions'];


     mysql_close($connection);


    ?>

<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

<p style="text-align: right;">
    <input name="Save_Btn" type="button" value="Save" />


    </p>


</form>
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: From just the information you've given. Yes.

Comment: Please can you explain better, I did not understand the question! :D

Comment: Jon Stirling And how can I do it with php? I updated the main question with the current code

Comment: @JellyBelly As you can see from the image, each record has a checkbox next to it, which is not part of the mysql table. I want to relate the checkbox to the record next to it, so I can save the data in a mysql table. Any idea how to code it with php ?

Comment: @Brian There is no checkbox in that image or code.

Comment: @Jon Stirling Sorry.. I meant combobox. I'm assuming I have to create a variable for each combobox with a loop or something?

Comment: @Brian So what is the new table you're inserting into? What have you got so far to insert into a second table?

Comment: @Jon Stirling basically I have two tables hs_hr_employees which I get data from to insert into the rights table. Then on the html table data from 4 columns is displayed from the rights table but it has an extra 5th column, which creates a combobox for each row in the table, therefore it is not linked with the mysql table. I want to link data input from the combobox with its current row data when the save button is clicked

Comment: @Brian From what I can see it looks like you've got the code to do this already. Is that correct? If so, is the issue that your update code isn't working, or in this case, running at all?

Comment: @Jon Stirling It IS creating the comboboxes, but they are not related to the record in the MySQL table. What I mean is that the comboboxes created are just 'random' comboboxes created with PHP for each row.

Comment: @Brian I'm saying it looks like you've for the SQL that you want to use already?

Comment: @Jon Stirling I did not understand you sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean another column after the select list column titled 'change'.
Add another table cell after the change colum with this...

```
echo "<td> <input type="checkbox" name='fieldName[]' value="<?php echo $row['emp_number']; ?>" > </td>";
```

After you've posted the form the $_POST['fieldName'] array will have the ids for the rows that have been clicked.

Try and make sure the $row['emp_number'] is from your tables primary key to make sure the value is unique.