# How to link html table to mysql table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table generated by PHP/mysql, I want a user to click the column/row to view the records related to the value clicked in the column/row **(2,2)**. Pl find below table  where I have Col Heading: **AR** and Row heading **Opening Bal**, When value 30 is clicked I need to pass row and column heading along with it so that I can search related records from the table.

Columns AR, N20, N2..... are dynamically created as per product table.

```
                AR    N20    N2
-------------------------------
1.Opening Bal   30    40     12
2.Received       5     2      3
3.Total 1+2     35    42     15
4.Sales          3     3      4
5.Total 3-4     32    39     11
-------------------------------
```

I need values to be passed to a php file where I can perform different validations and the display relevant records from more than one table.

```
mysql_query ("SELECT id from STOCKMASTER WHERE product='AR' AND openbal='30'");
```

Comment: A similar question has been asked .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566401/linking-html-table-with-mysql-table

Comment: @Challenger Solution give is not very precise, hence I am asking this again. kindly help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax crud. A very useful class to dynamically generate html to perform crud operations on your DB.

http://ajaxcrud.com/

Comment: Rajesh I want a simple way of doing this instead of AJAX.

Comment: You dont need to code anything in ajax here. Thats the beauty of this class. You need to use the php class as a wrapper . Please read the simple doc : Ever needed to provide easy "admin" access to a database table, but don't have the time/budget to code all the necessary actions you need (inserts, updates, deletes, etc...)? This PHP class allows you (and/or your clients) to get direct access to your data with a few lines of code. Short story: save time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jqgrid-
http://www.trirand.net/default.aspx